# Values of attributes in XML DOC

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xmldom

Im trying to get values of attribute in XML file, but always recieve message `"Object required"`.

**My JS code**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script
```

**loading xml**

```
        var x, i, txt;
            try{
            var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlDoc.async = false;
            xmlDoc.load("atm.xml");
            }
            catch(err){
            alert(err.message);
            }

        if(!xmlDoc){
        alert("Error");
        }

        x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("softKey")[0].attributes;
        alert(x.length);
        txt = x.getNamedItem("speech").nodeValue + "<br>" + x.length;
        alert(txt);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**and there is XMl File:**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<atmPage id="000" type="null" flash="" timeout="StandardTimeout" isEpp="false" isCancel="2" isFix="2" isOk="2" langCode="some text" skin="REGULAR" inputLength="0" popupGif="">
    <atmSoftKeys>
        <softKey index="1" text="some text " speech="some text" key="A" type="SOFT_KEY" langType="mu"/>
        <softKey index="2" text="some text" speech="some text" key="B" type="SOFT_KEY" langType="mu"/>
    </atmSoftKeys>
    <pageTitle title="some text" titleLangType="some text"/>
    <notification text="" notificationLangType="some text"/>
    <atmEppKeys/>
</atmPage>
```

Comment: Where did you get the idea to use `new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")`? Are you trying to script for old, outdated IE versions like IE 5 or IE 6?

Comment: Hey Martin, Yes, need it in IE6

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was simple,

```
var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = false;
        xmlDoc.load("Xml.xml");
        var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("softKey")[0].getAttribute("speech");
```